# Requirement for Namespace "Using java.lang;"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2010. There is a namespace "Using java.lang;" in the project and it is showing the error

> "The type or namespace name 'java' could not be found".

What should I do for this error. Have to install any package?

Comment: Wrong IDE??? Since when can you use Java in VS? (Apart from J#, which is outdated...)

Comment: Some of your project references must have a DLL with the namespace "java"

Comment: @bash.d well it would be possible to call a namespace "java.lang" but whether this makes sense is another thing... ;)

Comment: @MarcoForberg Too true! :)

Comment: @bash.d I use it for years. http://www.ikvm.net/

Answer (score 2):

Got solution. I did not add reference. Right click on project in solution explorer -> Property Pages -> References -> vjslib -> Add Reference -> Build project again.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace after a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) directive has to exist in the current project or in any referenced assembly in order to be recognized by the compiler.

Perhaps it would help if you could see what classes from the `java.lang` namespace are used in your project. Are there any classes in the project that give the *"are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?"* error?

When you search the web for "java.lang C#" and "java.lang .NET" you might find libraries like [IKVM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Run_a_jar_file_on_the_fly).

And yes, this is why documentation is important. Ask the creator of the project.